# What is the correct order of “times” at a dinner?

Tags: menu-planning

I need to know the correct order of "times" for serving dishes and creating a menu

Comment: How many courses? And the order of courses varies somewhat regionally as well, plus with how formal the dinner is. (But you can generally assume appetizers, then mains, then dessert. ;) )

Comment: Is it very necessary to serve dessert at a formal dinner?

Comment: I assume you mean “courses” - a sequence of dishes that together form a menu? The answer will depend on culture and traditions, context, level of formality and occasion.

Comment: What is “necessary” is also a question of cultural tradition (there are cuisines that don’t have the concept of dessert as part of a menu) and there are huge variations even within a culinary context. Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why did you add so many non-relevant tags to your question? none of it relates to what you're asking.

Comment: @Luciano the tags are fixable, but the question still needs clarification.

Comment: @Stephie sure, I just didn't want to fix it before OP had a chance to clarify the question